# Installing Xamarin for VS2013 professional

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin

I have Visual studio professional 2013 installed on Windows 10. Now I want to install Xamarin for this version of visual studio. How to do it, the xamarin installer online installs VS2015 community but I don't want VS2015. I want to use Xamarin on VS2013 professional.

Comment: https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1643349-missing-visual-studio-extensions-after-installation Should be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please check below link installing Xamarin with out visual studio 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/quick-start-tutorial-manual-or-quick-way-of-xamarin-and-simulator-installation/

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to visual studio gallery to get the [Xamarin installer extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dcd5b7bd-48f0-4245-80b6-002d22ea6eee)

Hope that can solve your problems.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful.